# Rails 3 + Devise 2 + JsonP / Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, jsonp

I'm working on a PhoneGap mobile app that communicates with a rails3 server using a REST api and json. Authentication is done using devise 2.0.4. 
For my own controllers I can specify that rails should wrap the json with the callback to handle the Cross-Domain problem by the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @books, :callback => params[:callback] }
end
```

notice the:

```
:callback => params[:callback]
```

I'm unable to do that with the devise controllers.
How can I get devise to respond to js requests - i.e. json with a callback?

Thanks a lot,

Ariel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to override devise controllers providing the :callback parameter to renderer or using before_filter somehow. In order to do that copy devise controller(s) from github/local-gem-directory to your app and then edit. But it would be much easier to define a JS views for each action:

If you ain't done it already start with generating devise views (which is not necessary but would help you to get the idea):

```
rails g device:views -s
```

It would generate lots of `*.html.erb` files inside of your `app/views/devise` folder. You have to create appropriate `*.js.erb` next to them with following contents:

```
<%=render :inline => params[:callback]+'('+resource.to_json+')'%>
```

**PS:** Actually you may just put that line into `app/views/application.js.erb` and skip other steps;)

Comment: As a reference make sure to check rails source out to look at way rails is adding a JSONP callback while rendering from controller.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L89-L99